# Transient voltage noise in 240 V AC mains detection circuit MSP430FR2311 gets RESET

Tags: filter, noise, power-electronics, mains, transient-suppression

I am detecting 240 V AC mains using optocoupler. Here is my circuit.

[image]

When I am doing this my microcontroller resets every time I on/off the 230V AC circuit.
I've seen response of the on & off switch in oscilloscope. It is looking like below image

[image]
Because of this transient my controller gets reset as the same transient is being seen in the reset pin and power pin of the controller.

Can anyone help with how to reduce this transient. I've tried low pass filter at output side by adding 330Ohm resistor with 10uF capacitor. Did not worked.

I've tried same thing with Arduino ATmega328P which does not reset with same transient.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to show where in the circuit your 'scope is connected.

Comment: It has connected to the pin going to uC. I've updated the drawing

Comment: If your 'scope is 2-channel can you monitor the 3.3 V supply as well and give an image? There is much information that you are not telling us: (1) What is your load? (2) What current? (3) What is the layout? Is the load well separated from the micro-processor? (4) A schematic.

Comment: And at 100 ns/div, show your scope connection.

Comment: I've no load I am just checking my 230V line on/off (I've directly connected 230V line and neutral to the above pins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved problem by having conversation with one of the Texas Instruments employee

In Texas Instruments MSP430FR2311 every I/O is having relationship with VCC and hence  MSP430 will reset cause by the VCC fluctuation, and the VCC fluctuation was caused by the input IO signal.

While in ATMEGA328P or some other controllers don't have these kind of problems and they can sustain a good amount of these kind of smaller transients.

So we've finally moved onto the ATMEGA328P.

More information can be found [here](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/676785)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit, as drawn, can't put more than 3.3V or less than zero volts on the uC pin. Yet, you're seeing that, so something else must be happening.  It seems likely that whatever 230VAC load you're switching is injecting noise into the power supply for the uC. Try putting your scope on the uC power supply, as close to it as you can get, and see what's there.  If you do see a transient there, that's the first thing to fix.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am powering my micro-controller from the debugger which is powered by my laptop battery hence there should not be any problem with the microcontroller power supply.

Comment: I've disconnected micro controller and only giving power supply from USB still same results obtained. Please help